# How to messaure run time of a program called by execvp?

Tags: linux, system-calls

My goal is to count time for the running of execvp program.
i want the program to run only 5 seconds tops;
how do i do it?

i want to know if the a.out ran under 5 seconds

```
void run_after_compilation(char **argv, int flag) {
    pid_t   runner;
    char *cmd [] = {"./a.out", NULL};
    int status;
    int fdin    = open(argv[2],O_RDONLY);
    int fdout   = open ("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0466);

    if ((runner = fork()) < 0) {error("could not make fork");}
    else if (runner == 0) {
        if ((execvp(cmd[0],cmd)) < 0 ) {}
        exit(0);
    } else if (runner != 0) {
        waitpid(runner,&status,0); // wait the execute to end

    }

    close(fdin);close(fdout);   /*closing the files*/
}
```

this is my thought:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (waitpid(runner,&status,WNOHANG) > 0)
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            break;
        } else {sleep(1);}

}
if(!WIFSTOPPED(status)) kill (runner, SIGUSR1);
```

Comment: All your questions tend to be of the type - here is my problem, solve it for me. Please attempt it yourself first, report back specific problems you encountered and perhaps someone will help you then.

Comment: i've added my thought - its still not working

Comment: I still don't get it! i've read a lot and i don't get it

Comment: Thank you for adding your attempt to the question. But please describe the exact problem you encountered. Not just "it doesn't work". But here is a tip from the man page for waitpid: "if WNOHANG was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned". Finally, a better solution would be to use a timer rather than a polling sleep.

Comment: i got it!
by myself ofcourse:)

Answer (score 0):

all i need is to check the waitpid(runner,&status,WNOHANG) each time, if the program has finished then the result would be differerent from 0 otherwise it hasn't finish.